# R: Using ddply from a subset of data to apply to each category of data

Tags: r

Like the title says, I am trying to take information from the subset of a category and apply it to a new column mapped to just that category, not the entire column.  What I have tried so far from the code below can be seen in df1 and df2, but it's not quite the results I want (see the inline comment to see the problem)

```
    library(ggplot2)
    df <- ToothGrowth
    df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)

    #takes the minimimum by category 'supp' and applies a subtract to each subset (only half of what I want)
    df1 <- ddply(df, .(supp), transform, min1 = len - min(len)) 
    #takes the entire minimum for dose=1 (which is 13.6) and applies a subtraction to the entire column
    df2 <- ddply(df, .(supp), transform, min1 = len - min(subset(df,df$dose==1)$len))
```

What I actually want is to find the minimum for dose=1 in both categories and subtract by category.

Therefore in the supp='OJ' category, the new min1 column should have all the values (for every dose) subtracted by 14.5 since it's the minimum len for dose=1.

Likewise, in the supp='VC' category, the new min1 column should have all the values (for every dose) subtracted by 13.6 since it's the minimum len for dose=1. My desired results are as follows:

```
    > df2
        len supp dose min1
    1  15.2   OJ  0.5  0.7
    2  21.5   OJ  0.5  7.0
    3  17.6   OJ  0.5  3.1
    4   9.7   OJ  0.5 -4.8
    5  14.5   OJ  0.5  0.0
    ...
    31  4.2   VC  0.5 -9.4
    32 11.5   VC  0.5 -2.1
    33  7.3   VC  0.5 -6.3
    34  5.8   VC  0.5 -7.8
    35  6.4   VC  0.5 -7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min(subset(df, dose==1)$len)` is taking the `min` of the 'len' where 'dose' is 1 for the whole dataset, so it will be a single value. (Also, we don't need to convert the 'dose' to `factor`). Instead, we need to get the `min` of 'len' for each 'supp'.  In that case, remove the `subset(df,` and just use `dose==1` to return a logical vector, get the corresponding 'len', get the `min` value and subtract from 'len'.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(supp), transform, min1 = len - min(len[dose==1])) 
#    len supp dose min1
#1  15.2   OJ  0.5  0.7
#2  21.5   OJ  0.5  7.0
#3  17.6   OJ  0.5  3.1
#4   9.7   OJ  0.5 -4.8
#5  14.5   OJ  0.5  0.0
#6  10.0   OJ  0.5 -4.5
#7   8.2   OJ  0.5 -6.3
#8   9.4   OJ  0.5 -5.1
#9  16.5   OJ  0.5  2.0
#10  9.7   OJ  0.5 -4.8
#11 19.7   OJ  1.0  5.2
#12 23.3   OJ  1.0  8.8
#13 23.6   OJ  1.0  9.1
#14 26.4   OJ  1.0 11.9
#15 20.0   OJ  1.0  5.5
#16 25.2   OJ  1.0 10.7
#17 25.8   OJ  1.0 11.3
#18 21.2   OJ  1.0  6.7
#19 14.5   OJ  1.0  0.0
#20 27.3   OJ  1.0 12.8
#21 25.5   OJ  2.0 11.0
#22 26.4   OJ  2.0 11.9
#23 22.4   OJ  2.0  7.9
#24 24.5   OJ  2.0 10.0
#25 24.8   OJ  2.0 10.3
#26 30.9   OJ  2.0 16.4
#27 26.4   OJ  2.0 11.9
#28 27.3   OJ  2.0 12.8
#29 29.4   OJ  2.0 14.9
#30 23.0   OJ  2.0  8.5
#31  4.2   VC  0.5 -9.4
#32 11.5   VC  0.5 -2.1
#33  7.3   VC  0.5 -6.3
#34  5.8   VC  0.5 -7.8
#35  6.4   VC  0.5 -7.2
#36 10.0   VC  0.5 -3.6
#37 11.2   VC  0.5 -2.4
#38 11.2   VC  0.5 -2.4
#39  5.2   VC  0.5 -8.4
#40  7.0   VC  0.5 -6.6
#41 16.5   VC  1.0  2.9
#42 16.5   VC  1.0  2.9
#43 15.2   VC  1.0  1.6
#44 17.3   VC  1.0  3.7
#45 22.5   VC  1.0  8.9
#46 17.3   VC  1.0  3.7
#47 13.6   VC  1.0  0.0
#48 14.5   VC  1.0  0.9
#49 18.8   VC  1.0  5.2
#50 15.5   VC  1.0  1.9
#51 23.6   VC  2.0 10.0
#52 18.5   VC  2.0  4.9
#53 33.9   VC  2.0 20.3
#54 25.5   VC  2.0 11.9
#55 26.4   VC  2.0 12.8
#56 32.5   VC  2.0 18.9
#57 26.7   VC  2.0 13.1
#58 21.5   VC  2.0  7.9
#59 23.3   VC  2.0  9.7
#60 29.5   VC  2.0 15.9
```

---

Or we can use a similar methodology with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(supp) %>%
    mutate(min1 = len - min(len[dose==1]))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, min1:= len - min(len[dose==1]), by = supp]
```

Comment: The plyr suggestion did exactly as I needed for my data.  Thank you so much!!!!!!